# Show that a closed convex ball implies the triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am given a function $\|\cdot\|: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ that satisfies all the conditions of a norm except the triangle inequality. And let:

$$ B = \{\mathbf v \in \Bbb R^2 \mid \|\mathbf v\| \leq 1 \}$$

I am asked to show that if $B$ is convex, namely if $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \in B, \: t\mathbf v + \left(1-t\right)\mathbf w \in B \:\:\: \forall t \in \left[0,1\right]$, then $\|\cdot\| $ satisfies the triangle inequality.

I have thought that maybe I can prove this by contradiction, assuming that there exists some pair of vectors that do not satisfy the triangle inequality under this function. However, I need to prove the result that:

$$ \|\mathbf v + \mathbf w\| > \|\mathbf v\| + \|\mathbf w\| \Rightarrow \|l\mathbf v + k\mathbf w\| > |l| \|\mathbf v\| + |k|\|\mathbf w \| \:\: \forall l,k \in \Bbb R$$

And I cannot seem to do this. If this result is true than I can consider the unit versions of the vectors and show that convexity forces the triangle inequality and thus, a contradiction. However, I cannot prove this result.

Would my approach work? Is there perhaps a shorter, more concise and neater approach that would achieve the desired proof? Any advice and help you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify why you think you need that result to obtain a contradiction? Note that for a contradiction, it's sufficient to find a single pair of vectors $v,w\in B$ and a single value $t\in[0,1]$ with $tv+(1-t)w\not\in B$; that is, you can choose $t$ based on what you have.

Comment: You're given a function that satisfies the triangle inequality, and you are being asked to show that it satisfies the triangle inequality? Please clarify.

Comment: @AOrtiz ahh, sorry that is a typo. It satisfies all conditions of a norm, except the triangle inequality.

Comment: @stewbasic Ahh, thank you! I figured it out thanks to what you said!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean that $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies all the conditions for a norm, except for the triangle inequality.

Since $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ for all scalars $\lambda$, it follows that $$\frac{x}{\|x\|}\in B$$
for non-zero $x$. But then:
$$\frac{v+w}{\|v\|+\|w\|}=\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\|+\|w\|}\frac{v}{\|v\|}+\frac{\|w\|}{\|v\|+\|w\|}\frac{w}{\|w\|}\in B$$
since $B$ is convex. Therefore, by the definition of $B$:
$$\frac{\|v+w\|}{\|v\|+\|w\|}\le 1$$

Comment: why $\frac{v+w}{\|v\|+\|w\|}\in B$?

Comment: @RafaelHolanda Because I've expressed it as a convex combination of $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ and $\frac{w}{\|w\|}$, both of which are in $B$.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I meant, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Reveillark I think you should remove the sentence "In particular..." since that inclusion is justified by the sentence afterwards (or replace by "In particular $v/\|v\|,\,w/\|w\|\in B$", since that's what you actually use).

Comment: @stewbasic Agreed, I edited accordingly, thanks!