# Convexity of the set with the fixed norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

These are the circles $\Vert x \Vert = a, a > 0$ for various norms of the form
$
\Vert x \Vert = \left(\sum_i |x_i|^p \right)^{1/p} 
$

[image]

And the $p = 1/2$ norm is not a norm, because it does not satisfy the triangle inequality :
$$
\Vert x + y \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert
$$
And the set, with the fixed norm is not convex, whereas for other cases it is.

*Does it hold for any norm, that the level set with the fixed norm is convex in order to satisfy the triangle inequality?*

Comment: Yes. You can prove that it is equivalent in the definition of a norm to ask that the triangle inequality is satisfied, or to ask that the unit ball is convex.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If I understand the question well, the OP asks if the convexity of the balls is *equivalent* to the triangle inequality. The answer is yes, but your link gives only one implication.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Then [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917250/show-that-a-closed-convex-ball-implies-the-triangle-inequality) will have the rest of the answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Indeed, thank you :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the links!